# How to change processor stack?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, stack, stack-pointer

Why doesn't this code print "test"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo ( void ) {
   printf("test\n");
}

__declspec(naked)
void bar ( void ) {
   asm {
      push 0x000FFFFF
      call malloc
      pop ecx
      push eax
      add eax, 0x000EFFFF

      mov ecx, esp
      mov esp, eax
      push ecx

      call foo

      pop esp
      call free
      pop ecx
      ret
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   bar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably make that 'printf("test\n");' in case there are buffering issues.

Comment: Nice challange for me. I did not code in asm for quite some time, had to refresh myself on calling conventions to compile this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because your newly allocated stack is not DWORD aligned. Change code to this:

```
  push 0x00100000
  call malloc
  pop ecx
  push eax
  add eax, 0x000f0000
```

... and it will print as needed.

Be sure to add \n to avoid buffering issues as advised by Paul.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

The funny or sad thing is that I have been reading an Intel x86 Architecture manual when I got too excited I just had to start coding.  The section I stopped on was Stack Align.  :)